# Will cooling of my silencer help my gun's effectiveness?

Tags: weapons

Will cooling down the projectile as it travels through the "Silencer" make it:

1. Hit the target with as much or less force?
2. Make it quieter?
3. Keep it just as accurate or better?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. This question seems strictly about ballistics (and as such I suspect the pertinent info can be found with an internet search), with no worldbuilding at all. Also mind that the projectile is cooled down anyway, so it is not even clear what you are asking

Comment: Why specifically have it cooled as it passes the silencer, as opposed to cooling it beforehand?

Comment: Cooling the barrel of the firearm is not only beneficial bit necessary on large guns like tanks. Without cooling,  the barrel wasps and losses precision over time.  . Cooling the noise suppressor would be like putting a screen door in a submarine.

Comment: I will watch the news closely now.

Comment: There is a contradiction between the title and the body of your question. The title asks about cooling the silencer, while the body of the question asks about the cooling of the projectile. Which do you want to ask about? Either or both? However, I'd like to know how to cool a bullet on its way through a silencer. That should be very tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Will thwart trajectory. The sudden cooling causes strain on its metallic surface, and alters its aerodinamics. Other than that

1) it won't alter the impact force, unless you make it pass through water thus slowing it down

2) won't make it quieter. it's the explosion that propels it that makes its start noisy.

Comment: You'd have some cool weapon though.

Comment: [Cold silencers slow down bullets in some cases](https://www.quora.com/Do-silencers-slow-the-muzzle-velocity-of-a-bullet) (but they have the opposite effect in other cases). There is, however, a non-negligible (but not significant) difference in muzzle velocity based on silencer temperature. One would assume that a projectile cooling mechanism would also affect silencer temperature.

Comment: don't forget whatever kit he has on his weapon to somehow cool the round as it passes through the suppressor may make more noise/effect the round

Comment: @flater but Cold Suppressors don't cool the projectile, just make the suppressor cooler to handle after firing

Comment: @BladeWraith: As mentioned, _one would assume that a projectile cooling mechanism would also affect silencer temperature._ Cold suppressors don't cool the projectile, but it's plausible that projectile cooling will also cool suppressors, which in turn effect muzzle velocity.

Comment: Noise suppressors  (aka silencers) offer minimal hearing protection to people in the immediate vicinity of the firearm. they don't actually contact the projectile,  or bring the noise level down to sage or even comfortable levels. Cooling the nose suppressor should have a negligible effect on the round speed and trajectory. I qualify that because a temperature gradient will introduce localized air currents, someone with sniper experience would need to pitch in about the effects of localized air currents on bullet trajectory.